# List of checkboxes with digestive-functors

Tags: haskell, digestive-functors

How do I use digestive functors to create a form that has a programmatically generated list of checkboxes, which would return a list. For example:

```
[x] Milk
[ ] Cereals
[x] Ground meat
```

would return `["Milk", "Ground meat"]`.

I'm expecting the type would be something like:

```
form :: (Functor m, Monad m) => [String] -> HappstackForm m Html BlazeFormHtml [String]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no standard way to do so, but `digestive-functors` is highly composable using the `Applicative` interface, so you can easily create what you want.

You can define a `checkBox` which returns a `Maybe String`, i.e. the name of the element if it was checked.

```
checkBox :: (Functor m, Monad m)
         => String -> HappstackForm m Html BlazeFormHtml (Maybe String)
checkBox str = fmap maybeStr (inputCheckBox False) <++ label str
  where
    maybeStr True  = Just str
    maybeStr False = Nothing
```

You can then loop over a list of strings to create a checkbox like this for each element in the list:

```
listForm' :: (Functor m, Monad m)
          => [String]
          -> HappstackForm m Html BlazeFormHtml [Maybe String]
listForm' = foldr (\x xs -> fmap (:) x <*> xs) (pure []) . map checkBox
```

The `catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]` helps you to reduce the result further:

```
listForm :: (Functor m, Monad m)
         => [String]
         -> HappstackForm m Html BlazeFormHtml [String]
listForm = fmap catMaybes . listForm'
```

And finally, we can instantiate the actual form:

```
food :: [String]
food = ["Milk", "Cereals", "Ground meat"]

foodForm :: (Functor m, Monad m)
         => HappstackForm m Html BlazeFormHtml [String]
foodForm = listForm food
```

Comment: `listForm'` can be written more simply using `Data.Traversable` as `listForm' = traverse checkBox`.