# how do I modify inputText to use inputCheckbox

Tags: haskell, digestive-functors, haskell-spock

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436238/list-of-checkboxes-with-digestive-functors), where for an element in list of strings, I have a checkbox next to it and figure out which checkbox is checked or not. Using examples from the internet, I was able to get an example running

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Monoid
import Data.String
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Text as T

import Web.Spock.Safe
import Web.Spock.Digestive

import Text.Blaze (ToMarkup(..))
import Text.Blaze.Html5 hiding (html, param, main)
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Utf8 (renderHtml)

import Text.Digestive
import Text.Digestive.Blaze.Html5

import System.Directory
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad (forM_)

gen :: Html -> [Html] -> Html
gen title elts  = H.html $ do
  H.head $
    H.title title
  H.body $
    H.ul $ mapM_ H.li elts

data CheckBox = CheckBox { postTitle :: T.Text }

checkboxForm = CheckBox
             <$> "title" .: Text.Digestive.text Nothing

renderForm :: View Html -> Html
renderForm v = do
  Text.Digestive.Blaze.Html5.form v "POST" $ do
    H.p $ do
          Text.Digestive.Blaze.Html5.label "title" v "Post title: "
          inputText "text" v
    inputSubmit "Submit Post"

main :: IO ()
main =
    runSpock 8080 $ spockT Prelude.id $ do
       get root $ do
           listing <- liftIO $ getDirectoryContents "/home/hasenov/mydir"
           let filteredListing = filter (\l -> not $ isPrefixOf "." l) listing
           (view, result) <- runForm "checkboxForm" checkboxForm
           case result of
               Nothing -> lazyBytes $ renderHtml (renderForm view)
               Just newCheckbox -> lazyBytes $ renderHtml (renderForm view)
--           lazyBytes $ renderHtml (gen "My Blog" (Data.List.map fromString filteredListing))
--       get ("hello" <//> var) $ \name ->
--           text ("Hello " <> name <> "!")
```

However, in the function renderForm, when I change inputText to something like **inputCheckbox "True"**, I get the error **True does not exist**. I am not able to find an example where inputCheckbox is used, I was hoping someone would help me adapt **filteredString** so it would display checkboxes next to it, and I can run the form properly. Also, in [previous link I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436238/list-of-checkboxes-with-digestive-functors), I don't know what the function **inputCheckBox**, since I could only find **inputCheckbox**. Perhaps this is an outdated function?

Comment: Can you provide all of your `import` statements? That would help a lot.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @ErikR, I added a comment below

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question since I figured out how to get **inputCheckbox** instead of **inputText**. Actually, [this example](https://github.com/jaspervdj/digestive-functors/blob/master/digestive-functors/Snap.hs) helped alot. It was the only one I could find which uses inputCheckbox. What I needed to do was change
    `data CheckBox = CheckBox { postTitle :: T.Text }`
to
    `data CheckBox = CheckBox Bool`
Then I could just initialized

```
checkboxForm = CheckBox
         <$> "title" .: bool (Just False)
```

Here is the full source:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Monoid
import Data.String
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Text as T

import Web.Spock.Safe
import Web.Spock.Digestive

import Text.Blaze (ToMarkup(..))
import Text.Blaze.Html5 hiding (html, param, main)
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Utf8 (renderHtml)

import Text.Digestive
import Text.Digestive.Blaze.Html5

import System.Directory
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad (forM_)

gen :: Html -> [Html] -> Html
gen title elts  = H.html $ do
  H.head $
    H.title title
  H.body $
    H.ul $ mapM_ H.li elts

data CheckBox = CheckBox Bool

checkboxForm = CheckBox
             <$> "title" .: bool (Just False)

renderForm :: View Html -> [Html] -> Html
renderForm v strings = do
  Text.Digestive.Blaze.Html5.form v "POST" $ do
    H.p $ mapM_ (\string -> do
      inputCheckbox "title" v
      Text.Digestive.Blaze.Html5.label "title" v string
      H.br) strings
    inputSubmit "Submit Post"

main :: IO ()
main =
    runSpock 8080 $ spockT Prelude.id $ do
       get root $ do
           listing <- liftIO $ getDirectoryContents "/home/ecks/btsync-gambino"
           let filteredListing = filter (\l -> not $ isPrefixOf "." l) listing
           (view, result) <- runForm "checkboxForm" checkboxForm
           case result of
               Nothing -> lazyBytes $ renderHtml (renderForm view (Data.List.map fromString filteredListing))
               Just newCheckbox -> lazyBytes $ renderHtml (renderForm view (Data.List.map fromString filteredListing))
--           lazyBytes $ renderHtml (gen "My Blog" (Data.List.map fromString filteredListing))
--       get ("hello" <//> var) $ \name ->
--           text ("Hello " <> name <> "!")
```